# Call ASP .NET Core API in Azure from daemon application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I have limited experience on `Azure AD` and authentication mechanism. So far I cannot figure out why is not working. Here is the scenario:

I have an `ASP net core 2.1` application deployed in `azure` web app service.
For authentication I’m using `Open ID` connect with `.AddOpenIdConnect` and provide `client_id, secret_id`, etc. When users are accessing my web API they are redirected to Microsoft login.

Now I need to expose an API to a third party application (scheduled web job) which is not in `Azure`.

I tried to use this sample from [Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2), only the console app, as I already have the `WebApp` in `Azure`.
Running the sample I’m able to get the token, but when I call my API the response is the HTML to Microsoft login page.

On `Azure` portal on

> *Enterprise Application -> daemon-console -> Activity -> Service Principal sign-ins*

I can see the success sign in.

Note: for testing I run the web app on my local machine and from the console application I’m calling API https://localhost:44306/api/test.

Asp .net core app:

```
services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(option =>
{
    option.Cookie.Name = "myWebApp"; 
    option.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    option.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(option =>
{
    option.ClientId = client_id;
    option.ClientSecret = client_secret;
    option.Authority = authority;
    option.SignedOutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:44306/";
    option.CorrelationCookie.Name = "myWebAppCorrelation"; 
    option.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    option.NonceCookie.Name = "WebAppNonce";
    option.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    option.Resource = "https://graph.windows.net";
    option.ResponseType = "id_token code";
})
```

Console app trying to access the API ( code extracted from Microsoft sample )

```
app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
    .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority))
    .Build();
    
result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync(); // ok

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var defaultRequestHeaders = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
if (defaultRequestHeaders.Accept == null || !defaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Any(m => m.MediaType == "application/json"))
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
defaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(webApiUrl);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // ok 
{
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // here I'm getting the HTML to login page
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(json);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    processResult(result);
}
```

The only difference between the sample code and my scenario is that the web app from sample is using `services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)                     .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration)`
but I cannot use `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` in Asp .Net core 2.1

Does anyone has an idea where the issue might be ? Do I need to add another authentication scheme ?

Comment: Why do you still need to log in when using the daemon? Which authentication flow are you currently using?

Comment: @CarlZhao, if I understand correctly, my web app is using implicit grant flow. I don't want to log in using daemon. I just need to expose an API from my web app for other application which is not in Azure. I was expecting once I got the token I will be able to call the the API, but instead the response from calling that API is the login page.

Comment: From your description. Is the web api you are calling not in Azure? However, the web api called in the sample you provided is exposed in Azure.

Comment: @CarlZhao, For testing this scenario I have both web API and console app on my local environment. I updated the description and added some code samples.

Comment: It's just a guess of mine, what will you get if you try to use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)?

Comment: The code samples from client credential flow are pointing to same daemon console app. I don't understand what I need to change. The only difference between the sample code and my scenario is that the web app from sample is using `services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);` but I cannot use AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi in asp net core 2.1

Comment: In my opinion, you can try to find a solution which allows specific ip address to bypass the authorization so that your third party application doesn't need to sign in when calling the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to support JWT authentication in addition to cookie authentication. So you need to add `AddJwtBearer`. You also need to extend the authentication check because you are now supporting multiple schemes.

This is how I would do it:

```cs
// public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, cfg => {
    cfg.Authority = authority;
    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = /*see scopes of your deamon app*/
    };
})
.AddCookie(option =>
{
    // ...
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(option =>
{
    // ...
})


// public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

app.UseAuthentication();
// https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1847
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            context.User = result.Principal;
        }
    }
    await next();
});
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. It worked by adding AddJwtBearer. However, I didn't add the middleware that perform `context.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`. Instead, I added  `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` on the specific API controller that I want to allow external app access. In this way only that API will use JWTBearer scheme. In this way, if I understand correctly, the rest of APIs are working with the default scheme, and only the specified one can be accessed by the daemon-app.

Comment: If you only want this to apply to certain controllers/routes, using the attribute is better than my suggestion. Thanks for sharing.